# retrofit2 получение данных

Tags: android, retrofit, android-threads

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Использую Retrofit. Ранее он вызывался асинхронным запросом в MainActivity (enqueue).
Теперь я разнёс логику  работы и все методы retrofit я перенёс в Application. Приложение работает, с сервера получает ответы.
Во fragment, где я обращаюсь к методу retrofit мне нужно получить данные из этого запроса и отобразить их в textview.
Для этого я создал переменную в Application, гетер к ней, и в методе enqueue я присваиваю её значение из запроса, а
потом во fragment я через геттер получаю нужное мне значение.
Проблема вот в чём. В логах видно, что после того, как Retrofit отправил запрос на сервер, происходит запрос через геттер к переменной, т.е. ещё до получения ответа. А после уже приходит ответ.
Когда запросы были в MainActivity после запроса, возвращался ответ.
Как я понимаю, тут используются разные потоки? И мне нужно как-то их синхронизировать?

Во fragment `    private App app;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    app = ((App)getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}
```

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:

```
            app.responseTranslator();

            textViewTranslate.setText(app.getResponseTranslator());

            break;`
```

В Application:

```
private String responseTranslator;
public String getResponseTranslator() {
    return responseTranslator;
}
```

...
public void responseTranslator() {
        Call call = apiTranslator.translate(mapJson);

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Translator>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Translator> call, Response<Translator> response) {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    responseTranslator = response.body().getText().toString();
                } else {
                    responseTranslator = getString(R.string.error_invalid_responce);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Translator> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

И лог:

```
04-21 13:54:01.790 3835-3835/com.example.alex.yandextranslator D/TabFragmentTranslator: Start onClick
```

04-21 13:54:01.790 3835-3835/com.example.alex.yandextranslator D/App: Start createMapJson
04-21 13:54:01.790 3835-3835/com.example.alex.yandextranslator D/App: Start responseTranslator
04-21 13:54:01.946 3835-3848/com.example.alex.yandextranslator D/Retrofit: --> POST https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate http/1.1
...
--> END POST (110-byte body)
04-21 13:54:01.946 3835-3835/com.example.alex.yandextranslator **D/TabFragmentTranslator: translation = null**
04-21 13:54:02.022 3835-3848/com.example.alex.yandextranslator D/Retrofit: <-- 200 OK https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate (77ms)
... <-- END HTTP (45-byte body)
04-21 13:54:02.026 3835-3835/com.example.alex.yandextranslator D/App: responseTranslator [сон]

Comment: Код бы показали, чтоли... Ну а вообще, посмотрите в сторону RxJava с его подписками на события, тем более, что retrofit уго нативно умеет.

Comment: @rjhdby Рано еще смотреть ему в сторону RxJava

Comment: Лог тут не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Логику работы с сетью лучше переносить в отдельный класс, а не писать в `Application`.
2. Работа с `Retrofit` основана на колбэках. Вызывая асинхронный методы, Вы передаете объект-колбэк (то, что Вы передавали в `enqueue`), метод которого должен вызваться, когда придет ответ.

Если целью является обработка результата во фрагменте, то вызывая метод ретрофита (где бы он не лежал), Вы должны в метод передать и колбэк. В теле колбэка необходимо описать работу с вьюшками фрагмента.

Comment: Я правильно Вас понял, что в моём случае call.enqueue, нужно выполнять только во фрагменте, где сетяться View?

Comment: Ну есть и более сложные и красивые архитектурные подходы, чтобы добиться такого результата, но да, на начальном этапе лучше так.

Comment: Вот здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/ Retrofit прописан в Application. Чем плох такой подход?

Comment: Там прописана инициализация ретрофита и формирование ссылки на Api, а не реализация конкретного сетевого запроса. А Ваш подход при увеличении количества методов в API засорит класс Application ненужным ему кодом, в котором должен находиться лишь код инициализации различных зависимостей при старте приложения (например, фабрики, менеджер доступа к БД, менеджер работы с сетью и т.д.).